# How to performantly compare and merge similar objects while adding them to a set

Tags: java, performance, set, thread-safety, comparator

This might be a tad tricky, and I'm not sure if it's even considerd a "don't".

My setup is as follows:

I get an input of objects with 4 fields (ID, timestamp, type and value). I have to insert those following the order of their timestamp into a set. So far so easy:

```
ConcurrentSkipListSet<ScheduleElement> storage = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(new SEComparator());
```

Now the tricky part: a small percentage of the objects come from the same "asset" and need to be merged. Basically whenever there is a "duplicate" (same ID, timestamp and type) they have to be merged into one by adding the value.

I could easily do this with two separate steps.

BUT in that case I'd have to go over the (rather lengthy) Set twice. Given that performance is rather critical, I'd prefer not to do so.

My first idea was, to change my comparator in a way, that on a compareTo = 0, the value of object 1 is increased by the value of object 2 WHILE comparing. Object 2 is dropped due to the comparator returning 0.

```
public class SEComparator implements Comparator {

public int compare(ScheduleElement o1, ScheduleElement o2) {
    int i = (o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime()));
    if (i == 0) {
        i = (o1.getId()).compareTo(o2.getId());
        if (i == 0) {
            i = (o1.getType().compareTo(o2.getType()));
            if (i == 0) {
                o1.setValue(o1.getValue()+o2.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}

@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
}
```

Now being rather inexperienced with coding, I can't even start guessing if such a hack would break something totally unexpected.

Is this a total hack that should be avoided? Or if not, do you have any experience with critical spots for such a solution?

Comment: The `compare()` method should **compare** values. It is not allowed to update/mutate them!!! One reason is that you have no control over how it's called, e.g. whether it's called with `old, new` or `new, old`. Although you might get it to work right now, any other version of Java might break the code, because you are **violating** the use of `compare()`.

Comment: Thank you, so it's a "don't". That answers my question.

Comment: Not answering your question, but: Don't use `Comparator`, use `Comparator<ScheduleElement>`. This way you'll get rid of the useless and non-implementable `compare`. +++ I guess, `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is the `Map` you want. Note that nearly every Java set is based on a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to **key** by `ID`, `timestamp`, `type` and update `value` for data with those same **key** fields, then you need a `Map`, not a `Set`.

Notice how I highlighted **key** above? That is because a `Map` consists of a **key** and a **value**.

So, create a key class with the three key fields. Whether you want the map's value to be just the value or to be the full `ScheduleElement` is entirely up to you.

Comment: There is no need for a key at this place. The set is just a temporary storage buffer, for threads to grab what they need.

But it's mandatory that this storage is filled in a timely manner, as the input comes from a DB and thus is rather slow compared to the consumers.

Comment: You said your performance is the problem. I just told you how to fix that. If you refuse to accept that, that's your loss.

Comment: Doesn't the building of a new map slow it down more than can be gained from it? I didn't intend to refuse your answer, I just can't see the benefit in it (yet).

Comment: What do you mean "new map"? I'm saying to *replace* the `Set` with a `Map`.

Comment: I hear you. The reason why I've gone with the set is: I need the objects in an ordered, unique, concurrent collection. None of the maps I looked into, offered the combination, that's why I've gone with the ConcurrentSkipListSet, which does.

So to use a map would mean to introduce a middle step, which I try to avoid.